# Pulling array from object

Tags: javascript

Im trying to pull the gpa numbers from the array that is in the object and have them displayed in the console but my code keeps giving me undefined '0' error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var fsInfo = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    address:{
        street: '123 Some Street ',
        city: 'Town, ',
        state: 'HI',
    gpa: [3.0,4.0,2.0]
    }
 }

console.log("GPA: " + fsInfo.gpa['0'],fsInfo.gpa['1'],fsInfo.gpa['2'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
console.log("GPA: " + fsInfo.gpa[0],fsInfo.gpa[1],fsInfo.gpa[2])
```

**Note:** Array indices are numbers.

In your case, they are inside `address`. So you should do

```
console.log("GPA: " + fsInfo.address.gpa[0],fsInfo.address.gpa[1],fsInfo.address.gpa[2])
```

If your object had been like this

```
var fsInfo = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    address:{
        street: '123 Some Street ',
        city: 'Town, ',
        state: 'HI'
    },
    gpa: [3.0,4.0,2.0]
 }
```

then

```
console.log("GPA: " + fsInfo.gpa[0],fsInfo.gpa[1],fsInfo.gpa[2])
```

will work.

Comment: You *can* use non-integer indices, but in JavaScript that's an object.  In this object, `gpa` is a non-numeric index to the array.  You're correct here, though - the indexes are int, not string.

Comment: Wow didn't even see I closed it in the wrong location. I feel so stupid lol. Thanks alot